# How to format an array as labels and values in JavaScript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, dictionary

I'm still new to Angular and I'm trying to get a chart for my data using FusionCharts.
FusionCharts uses the following format to get the data.

```
const chartData = [{
      label: "2021-09-26T00:01:00",
      value: "250"
    },
    {
      label: "2021-09-26T00:02:00",
      value: "251"
    },
    {
      label: "2021-09-26T00:03:00",
      value: "245"
    },
    {
      label: "2021-09-26T00:04:00",
      value: "248"
    },
    {
      label: "2021-09-26T00:05:00",
      value: "251"
    },];
```

I got two separate arrays as values and labels. How can I convert them to this format.

I tried using dictionaries, but it has {label: value} format that can't be used with FusionCharts

Comment: Can you provide the sample data for *two separate arrays as values and labels* as mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: I tried doing that but the chart outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should just be a simple [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation:

```js
const labels = ['2021-09-26T00:01:00', '2021-09-26T00:02:00'];
const values = ['250', '251'];

const result = labels.map((label, i) => ({ label, value: values[i] }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of map() operation.

Comment: Yes. I tried it on and accepted. Thanks.